# Fixing starttls verify=fail, verifymsg=unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: smtp, sendmail, smarthost

Running Amazon Linux on EC2 instance with `sendmail`. I have an email account with Network Solutions, and use that account as a `SMART_HOST` relay in my `sendmail` configuration. It works well except for one little detail.

In  my `maillog` file I see entries like this:

```
sendmail[28450]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.example.com.netsolmail.net., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
```

After a little research, I've come to the conclusion that the `verify=FAIL` is essentially harmless: the connection actually was encrypted, it's just that the host's certificate could not be verified.

Since nobody but me reads the log file, I wouldn't care. But when the message arrives, the `Received` header shows

```
Received: from unknown (HELO example.com) (info@example.com@12.34.56.78)
  by 0 with ESMTPA; 15 Aug 2016 07:10:15 -0000
```

I was hoping to see `with ESMPTSA` but I would guess that the certificate verification failure caused the 'S' to be surpressed.

How can I get more detail on what was wrong with the certificate, and how can avoid the verification failure? My guess is that the multiple subdomains of `mail.example.com.netsolmail.net` don't match closely enough with the name on the certificate. But how can I verify that, and how can I avoid the complaint - or more exactly how can I get the `Received` header to acknowledge the secure connection with `ESMTPSA`.

EDIT: I edited `sendmail.mc` to add

```
define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `15')dnl
```

Now maillog gives more details. Right after the `verify=FAIL` line I now see:

```
sendmail[30706]: STARTTLS=client, cert-subject=/OU=GT39680792/OU=See+20www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps+20+28c+2915/OU=Domain+20Control+20Validated+20-+20RapidSSL+28R+29/CN=*.hostingplatform.com, cert-issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust+20Inc./CN=RapidSSL+20SHA256+20CA+20-+20G3, verifymsg=unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I take this to mean that at least one cause of the verification failure is that sendmail can't find a certificate for the local machine it's running on? Since I'm only relaying outgoing mail to a netsol server, never accepting incoming mail from the internet, I didn't think I'd need to have a certificate for this server. If I need one, where/how do I install it? And can it be the same certificate I use for my webserver, or do I need a different one? Would use of a self-signed certificate be good enough to get the `Received` header to say `with ESMTPSA`, or would it need to be a commercial certificate from a CA?

EDIT #2:

I'm accepting the answer by @MadHatter. The key was getting `confCACERT` defined. I'm embarrassed, my only excuse is old senile brain not grocking m4 source. The default sendmail.mc file on Amazon Linux already had

```
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
```

in it, and I had verified that the file existed. **But** I failed to notice the sneaky little `dnl` that was actually at the beginning of those lines! I know what it means, but since I very rarely look at m4 source, and it was right after some other `dnl`-ed lines that were marked as comments with `#`, my brain registered them as **not** being commented out!

I actually went through a bunch of gyrations downloading certs from Firefox and pointing sendmail at the Digicert certificate that I use for our website, but since this host only ever sends, never receives, email, nothing else was necessary. I put back the `dnl` on the defines for `confSERVER_CERT` and `confSERVER_KEY`, and all was well, with `maillog` showing `verify=OK` and `verifymsg=ok` on the appropriate `STARTTLS=client` lines.

But even though there were no diagnostics about TLS, the `Received` header for the connection to netsol still shows `with ESMTPA` and not `with ESMTPSA`. Oh well, @MadHatter had the dope on that one, too. Sorry this was so long and sort of a wild goose chase. But I learned a lot, and I did improve my configuration (in a non-vital way). I hope someone desperate enough to wade through this might learn something, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very much a question in parts, and I'll take it as such.  I've used `sendmail` as my preferred MTA for some decades, but I can't claim to be an expert in it (ie, I'm not Eric Allman).

> `verifymsg=unable to get local issuer certificate`
>
> I take this to mean that at least one cause of the verification
>   failure is that sendmail can't find a certificate for the local
>   machine it's running on?

This seems to be [an OpenSSL message, rather than an MTA one](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/what-means-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/12517/3), and as I understand it it means that the verifying app is unable to get local copy of the issuer's certificate.  In other words, sendmail doesn't have access to a certificate bundle that includes the root certificate for whoever issued the remote server's certificate. Remember that Linux doesn't provide a centralised certificate management service, so each app must roll its own bundle.  In my case, I gave sendmail access to a certificate bundle with the following m4 code:

```
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.with.intermediate.crt')dnl
```

> I was hoping to see with ESMPTSA but I would guess that the
>   certificate verification failure caused the 'S' to be surpressed.

I think that guess is wrong.  RFC2821 and 2822 are pretty elastic about the format of a Received: header, and I cannot find anything therein that distinguishes between `ESMTPA` and `ESMPTSA` (sic).  My headers all show lines such as:

```
Received: from example.com (example.com [80.70.90.61])
    by lory.teaparty.net (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id u6G25OXi006577
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA bits=256 verify=FAIL)
    for <me@example.net>; Sat, 16 Jul 2016 03:05:24 +0100
```

To understand what your receiver's MTA means by `ESMTPA`, you'd have to find out what that MTA is, and read the documentation.  Until you've done that, I don't think you can read much into that collection of letters.

> Can I avoid starttls `verify=fail` when server hostname does not match certificate

I don't think you can.  The fundmental idea behind SSL is that **(a)** the hostname you connect to **(b)** offers a certificate signed by a trusted third-party **(c)** with that hostname in either the CN or an SAN field.  If any of those properties is not met, it is right that SSL notes that it can't verify the identity of the peer.

You shouldn't read too much into it; self-signed certificates are still very common in email handling.  Of my last 1919 TLS-secured emails sent/received, 1764 involved a peer whose identity could not be verified for some reason, whilst only 155 could.  You yourself are running with a self-signed certificate; you should therefore be happy that most people don't really care about the trust-chain on SMTP TLS peers!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, the certificate bundle part especially! But even though I'm clearly a novice with this stuff, there are parts I question. ESMTPA and ESMTPSA are documented in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3848. You don't see either one in most Received headers because transfers between MTAs don't connect that way. But for a connection that uses auth, you should see "with ESMTPA". And if it also used TLS, you should see "with ESMPTSA". My connection to netsol produced "with ESMTPA"; if it used TLS, it should have said "with ESMPTSA". You disagree?

Comment: You're no doubt right about MTA's not necessarily following RFC 3848 with their Received headers, but since I do get ESMTPA on an authenticated connection, I think it's reasonable to expect ESMTPSA if it's also secure. I agree that my interpretation of verify=fail is probably wrong, so I should fix the title of the question. Minimally I need to install a certificate bundle (hmm, where to find and how to do), and then see what happens to verifymsg, and then either accept your answer or edit the question with more info.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to RFC3848.  I note that firstly the `A` is reserved for SMTP AUTH, which we have not discussed at all, and secondly, my sendmail (8.14.4) does not use them, as you can see - despite it offering TLS to every single incoming email.  As for bundles, I think I stole mine from my desktop firefox installation, if memory serves.

Comment: Hmm, the question showed I was getting ESMTPA, and indeedNetwork Solutions requires authentication. Maybe your server doesn't do auth, but only TLS? The RFC doesn't specify a "with" type for that situation, so that would explain why you don't see it. I'd think that sendmail 8.14.4 would support the RFC in its default configuration, so another possibility is that something put in you configuration over the years blocks it?

Comment: No, RFC3848 is pretty clear that `ESMTPS` is for STARTTLS without SMTP AUTH.  My sendmail, as I have shown, indicates a successful STARTTLS connection (and, for what it's worth, SMTP AUTH) in other ways.  As you say, NetSol are responsible for adding this `Received:` line, so in the end only they can say why they're not doing it.  I'm glad all the certificate bundle stuff was helpful, though!

Comment: Of course you're right. I swear I saw a table of these keywords that failed to include ESMTPS, which is why I said that. But the table I remember seeing is not in the RFC at all, which clearly lists and explains it in a bullet point. I need to be more careful checking references!